# care for minors / care of minors / guardianship of minors

Tags: phrases

Which of the phrases best describes the general responsibility for people who are under-age?

care for minors / care of minors / guardianship of minors

Comment: Possibly *guardianship of* might not seem so bad in a formal legal context, but in general you should stick to *care of* (or *caring for*, depending on the exact context/stylistic choice).

Comment: I'm going to use the phrase in the context of legal history, so I hope _guardianship_ will be a good choice. Thx for help.

Comment: I think "guardianship" refers to a particular adult's legal responsibility for a particular minor who is not their biological child - for example an adopted child, a child living with foster-parents, etc. A more general term for the responsibility of adults towards children is "duty of care". For example if you are driving a car and see a child riding a bike, you have a "duty of care" to take account of the fact that the child may do something unpredictable, even if there some other adults around who appear to be taking responsibility for the child.

Comment: @shogun I think you need to clarify your question.  "Duty of care" , "guardianship or custody", "parental responsibilities" are all correct, depending on the context, but are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - I misunderstood your question.  It looks like you don't mean daily care but **the responsibility until a minor becomes of age**.  In this case I would say **"guardianhip or custody of minors"**

If you mean a professional looking after a child and being paid for that, just as we say **"elderly care"** or **"aged care"**, you can say **"child care".**

**"child care"** (or childcare) refers to the care of a child during the day by a person other than the child's parents or legal guardian.  That's often available as a specialized child care facility or a formal institution where games, sports and  preschool education are all included.  Informally, however, child care is often provided through informal arrangements with nannies, baby sitters or even family members like a grandparent, uncle or aunt.

> - [child care](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=care+of+the+elderly&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source%3F%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=EsjhVam5K4OWwATDqo_4BQ#safe=off&q=child+care+definition) (definition) - the care of children by a day-care center, babysitter, or other provider while parents are working.-

Comment: Also "parental responsibilities."